# Cypress picking up spec files

Tags: angular, jasmine, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

Cypress seems to be incorrectly picking up my Jasmine spec files when running component tests:

[image]

[image]

I import the Account Service into my `toolbar.component.cy.ts` component so that I can add it to the providers array:
[image]

This is the config for Cypress:

```
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";

export default defineConfig({
  component: {
    devServer: {
      framework: "angular",
      bundler: "webpack",
    },
    specPattern: "**/*.cy.ts",
  }
});
```

Has anyone else had this issue before? If so, how do you fix it?!

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you accidentally import the `account.service.spec.ts` file at the top of the `toolbar.component.cy.ts`?

Comment: Actually yes I have! Removing this import has resolved the issue. Thanks. If you add it as an answer, I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in a comment, but as we learned, it looks like you had the file imported at the top of your test file. :)